# react-navigation Deep Linking opens app but not to correct page

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

**Problem**

I'm trying to setup Deep Linking and it doesn't open to the correct screen specified in my URL.  The app opens but always to the current screen instead of the screen specified in the URL.

My app has the following navigation structure and I'm trying to navigate to the Notifications screen when the app opens

1. Top level Switch Navigator

   1. SplashScreen
   2. AuthLoading Screen
   3. App (BottomTabNavigator)

      1. Home
      2. Profile
      3. Notifications
   4. Auth

**What I've tried**

I've tried setting up a new app and following their [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/3.x/deep-linking.html) and it works properly in the new project but I can't get it to work in my current project.  I've also included redux in the new project to test the same environment.

I'm testing by running `xcrun simctl openurl booted esportsdeeplink://app/notifications` for iOS and `adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d  “esportsdeeplink://app/notifications” com.benji.esportscompetition` for android.

Both have the same result of opening the app but not navigating to the specified page

**Enviornment**

- react-native v0.60.4
- react-navigation v3.11.1
- redux v4.0.4
- react-redux v7.1.0

***Code***
I've tried to include all relevant code but cut down some imports and other code to try to be concise.  I can post any additional code if you find it to be helpful

**Index.js (entry point)**

```
import App from './src/app/App';

const ReactNativeRedux = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={<SplashScreen />} persistor={persistor}>
      <PushNotifications />
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => ReactNativeRedux);
```

**App.js**

```
import AppContainer from './Components/BottomNavigation/NavigationRouting';

class App extends React.Component {
  render(props) {
    const prefix = 'esportsdeeplink://'
    console.log('prefix', prefix)
    return (
      <Fragment>
          <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor }}>
          <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
            <LoadingSpinner loading={this.props.loading} />
            <AppContainer
              ref={(navigatorRef) => {
                NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
              }}
              uriPrefix={prefix}
              screenProps={{
                http,
                saveFriendsFnUser: this.saveFriendsFnUser,
                signupComplete: this.signupComplete,
              }}
            />
          </View>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  loading: state.api.loading,
  user: state.user,
  math: state.math,
  response: state.response,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  startupRequest: () => {
    dispatch(startupRequest());
  },
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(App);
```

**NavigationRouting.js (where my navigators are created)**

```
const BottomTabNav = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileStack
    },
    Notifications: {
      screen: Notifications,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
         tabBarVisible: false
       }),
      path: 'notifications',
    },

  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: CustomTabNav,
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      SplashScreen,
      AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
      App: {
        screen: BottomTabNav,
        path: 'app',
      },
      Auth: {
        screen: AuthStack,
        path: 'auth'
      }
    }
  )
);
```

***Deep Linking Setup***

**iOS**

[image: iOS setup]

projectFolder/ios/eSportsCompetition/AppDelegate.m

```
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}

@end
```

**Android**

projectFolder/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="esportsdeeplink" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting under `uriPrefix={...}` `enableURLHandling={true}`

I also have added this in my AppDelegate.m file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:app openURL:url options:options];
}
```

This works for me when the app is running in the background but not when the app is killed.